Choose $6$ size-$14$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,200\}$ with union size $60$, uniformly. Find the expected size of the union of the first $4$ subsets
Let $ A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6 $ be randomly and uniformly chosen subsets of $ \{1, 2, \ldots, 200\} $ such that $ |A_i| = 14 $ for each $ i $, and $ |\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i| = 60 $. I am trying to determine the expected value of $ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| $.
I approached the problem as follows:
The total size of the union can be approximated by the formula:
$$
|\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i| \approx \sum_{i=1}^6 |A_i| - \binom{6}{2} |A_1 \cap A_2|
$$
This gives us:
$$
60 = 6 \times 14 - 15x
$$
where $ x = |A_1 \cap A_2| $. Solving for $ x $, we find:
$$
60 = 84 - 15x \implies 15x = 24 \implies x = \frac{24}{15} = 1.6
$$
Now, to find $ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| $, we can use a similar approach:
$$
|\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| \approx \sum_{i=1}^4 |A_i| - \binom{4}{2} |A_1 \cap A_2|
$$
This leads to:
$$
|\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| = 4 \times 14 - 6 \times 1.6 = 56 - 9.6 = 46.4
$$
However, this value is still an approximation. I am looking for a more precise expected value of $ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| $.

Linearity is your friend here.  What's the probability that a single integer $n$ is in all of the $A_i$?

Should say:  I think your intent is clear here, but you should indicate that the $6$ selections are chosen uniformly from all $\binom {200}{14}$ subsets of the desired size, independently of each other.  In particular, it's possible (though unlikely) that all $6$ of the $A_i$ coincide. If you meant something else, you should edit your post to explain,.

@lulu Yes, they are uniformly chosen. I also agree that the probability of a non-empty intersection among all six subsets is quite low. However, since it is given that the size of their union is 60, there may indeed be an element in the intersection.

Uniformity wasn't my question.  My question was independence.  As to your second thought, of course the expected value is small, but it is certainly positive.

I believe that the constraint of having a union size of 60 creates a dependency among all the subsets $A_i$

Oh, you are right.  I ignored that requirement.  Yes, you definitely need to take that into account. You'll need to consider the possible intersections.

You can save the question as a conditional expectation: each $A_i$ is independently a random sample size $14$ without replacement from  ${1, 2, \ldots, 200}$ with all possibilities being equally likely, and  you are looking for $\mathbb E\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| ,\Big|, |\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i|=60\right]$.

Not so easy to simulate: only about $0.02%$ of cases have $|\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i|=60$. The expected value seems likely to be between $45$ and $46$.

@Henry You’re right; the experimental average value is 43.3. However, I don't know how to calculate it theoretically.

$43.3$ looks too low to me.

@Henry I am really sorry. That is a typo. It was 45.3.

@AbulKalam My simulation gave about $45.7$. The exact conditional expectation is $45.53845$ up to rounding.

It is possible to approach this by simulation, but the result will not be precise because $60$ unique values after $6$ draws occurs in about 0.02% of cases.  For example using R simulating a million times, I got an estimate of the conditional expectation  $\mathbb E\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| \,\Big|\, |\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i|=60\right]$ of about $45.7$ but this should not be expected to be precise even to the first decimal place; in fact the theoretical value is $45.53845$.
U4U6 <- function(){
A1 <- sample(1:200, 14)
A2 <- sample(1:200, 14)
A3 <- sample(1:200, 14)
A4 <- sample(1:200, 14)
A5 <- sample(1:200, 14)
A6 <- sample(1:200, 14)
U4 <- unique(c(A1, A2, A3, A4))
U6 <- unique(c(U4, A5, A6))
return(c(length(U4), length(U6)))
}

set.seed(2024)
sims <- replicate(10^6, U4U6()) # slow
sum(sims[2,] == 60) # number simulations of 60 unique after 6 draws
# 203
table(sims[1, sims[2,]==60])
# 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
#  1  2  4 15 35 35 41 41 15  8  6 
mean(sims[1, sims[2,]==60]) # simulated conditional expectation
# 45.68966

It is possible to do the theoretical calculations using conditional probability, as each additional draw is in effect a hypergeometric distribution on the numbers not selected so far. First find the distribution of unique values seen after $4$ draws:
initialdraws <- function(numberdraws, total=200, draw=14){
  if(numberdraws == 1){
    probs <- numeric(total)
    probs[draws] <- 1
    return(probs)
    }
  extradraws(numberextradraws=numberdraws-1, initial=draw, total, draw)
  }  

extradraws <- function(numberextradraws, initial, total=200, draw=14){
  probunique <- numeric(total)
  probunique[initial] <- 1  
  for (drawnumber in 1:numberextradraws){  
    newprobunique <- numeric(total)
    for (already in 1:total){
      possfuture <- already:total   
      newprobunique[already:total]  <- newprobunique[already:total] + 
             probunique[already] *
             dhyper(possfuture-already, total-already, already, draw)
      }
    probunique <-  newprobunique
    }
  probunique
  } 

probsafter4 <- initialdraws(numberdraws=4, total=200, draw=14)
# plot(table(sims[1, ]) / length(sims[1,]))
# points(probsafter4) 
sum((1:200) * probsafter4) # unconditional expectation after 4 draws
# 50.3896

Then for each of those values, find the probability of reaching exactly $60$ after a further $2$ draws, and use $\mathbb P\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| =n \,\Big|\, |\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i|=60\right] = \frac{\mathbb P\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i|=60 \,\Big|\, |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| =n \right]\mathbb P\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| =n \right]}{\sum\limits_m \mathbb P\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i|=60 \,\Big|\, |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| =m \right]\mathbb P\left[ |\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i| =m \right]}$ to get the conditional distribution for the number after $4$ draws given there are $60$ after $6$ draws, and thus the conditional expectation of $45.53845$.
probs4then2more <- matrix(0, nrow=200, ncol=200)
for (possafter4 in which(probsafter4 > 0)){
  probs4then2more[possafter4, ] <-  probsafter4[possafter4] * 
      extradraws(numberextradraws=2, initial=possafter4, total=200, draw=14)
  }

sum(probs4then2more) # should be 1
# 1
sum((1:200) * colSums(probs4then2more)) # unconditional expectation after 6 draws
# 70.60196
colSums(probs4then2more)[60] # probability of 60 unique after 6 draws
# 0.0001947437

probs4given6is60 <- probs4then2more[, 60] / sum(probs4then2more[, 60])
# plot(table(sims[1, sims[2,]==60]) / sum(sims[2,]==60))
# points(probs4given6is60) 
sum((1:200) * probs4given6is60) # conditional expectation after 4 given 60 after 6
# 45.53845


I'm unsure about how to theoretically calculate those probabilities. Could you please clarify this @Henry ?

@AbulKalam The first draw, you get $14$ unique numbers with probability $1$.  The number of extra unique numbers you get on the second draw has a hypergeometric distribution.  The number of extra unique numbers you get on the third draw has a hypergeometric distribution which depends on how many unique numbers after the second draw. And so on.    The code in extradraws() implements this based on the number of extra draws, the initial number of unique numbers, the total number of numbers, and the size of each draw.  So you can get from $0$ to $4$ and from $4$ to $6$.

You can also check it is doing the right thing: the expected number of unique numbers after $4$ draws is 200*( 1-(1-14/200)^4) i.e. 50.3896 and after $6$ draws is 200*( 1-(1-14/200)^6) i.e. 70.60196, both of which appear in my answer.  And being fairly close to the simulation despite the small number of cases is also encouraging.
